# How to replace the content in webpage in Google Chrome extension every 5 seconds?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing a simple chrome extension which should replace the particular content of the webpage every 5 seconds?

Whether it's possible to anything like that?

This is my function (This would replace particular content)

```
replaceText(document.body.innerHTML);
```

How to run this function every x seconds in my script 'myscript.js'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `setTimeout`. It will look something like this:

```
function timedFunction() {
    replaceText(document.body.innerHTML);
    setTimeout("timedFunction()",5000);
}

timedFunction();
```

Comment: Where I should place it? in background.html or myscript.js?

Comment: That should be in your `myscript.js`. To communicate between your contentscript and background page you need messaging.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setTimeout()`.

See [w3schools timing events reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).